# Login no funciona en PHP con MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

**Buenas!**

Tengo un problema: mi login en PHP no funciona. El problema es que cuando pongo un usuario erroneo igual funciona, cosa que obviamente no debería de pasar.

No tengo ni idea de porqué pasa eso.

Acá el código del login:

```
<?
    session_start();
    // Obtengo los datos cargados en el formulario de login.
    $ci = $_POST['ci'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Datos para conectar a la base de datos.
    $nombreServidor = "censurado";
    $nombreUsuario = "censurado";
    $passwordBaseDeDatos = "censurado";
    $nombreBaseDeDatos = "censurado";

    // Crear conexión con la base de datos.
    $conn = new mysqli($nombreServidor, $nombreUsuario, $passwordBaseDeDatos, $nombreBaseDeDatos);

    // Validar la conexión de base de datos.
    if ($conn ->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn ->connect_error);
    }

    // Consulta segura para evitar inyecciones SQL.
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM a_usuarios WHERE ci='%s' AND password='%s'", mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $ci), mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password));
    $resultado = $conn->query($sql);

    // Verificando si el usuario existe en la base de datos.
        if($resultado){
            // Guardo en la sesión el ci del usuario.
            $_SESSION['ci'] = $ci;

            // Redirecciono al usuario a la página principal del sitio.
            header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily"); 
            header("Location: https://ejemplo.com"); 
        } else {
            echo 'El email o password es incorrecto, <a href="index.html">vuelva a intenarlo</a>.<br/>';
        }?>
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: session_start() va después de haber validado el usuario contra la base de datos, luego de eso debes usar session_start() para usar las variables de sesion.

Comment: @RobertoPaillao Igual no funcionó. Sigue redirigiendo a la página principal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con if($resultado) solo estás verificando que se haya ejecutado la consulta amigo. Para verificar que en verdad exista un registro con los datos ingresados, podrías cambiarlo a if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0). Quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0){
    // Guardo en la sesión el ci del usuario.
    $_SESSION['ci'] = $ci;

    // Redirecciono al usuario a la página principal del sitio.
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily"); 
    header("Location: https://ejemplo.com"); 
} else {
      echo 'El email o password es incorrecto, <a href="index.html">vuelva a intenarlo</a>.<br/>';
}
```

Espero y te ayude :)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funcionó :)

Answer (score 0):

Para validar si existe el usuario hay que verificar si regresa registros la consulta, con `mysqli_num_rows`

```
<?
    // Obtengo los datos cargados en el formulario de login.
    $ci = $_POST['ci'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Datos para conectar a la base de datos.
    $nombreServidor = "censurado";
    $nombreUsuario = "censurado";
    $passwordBaseDeDatos = "censurado";
    $nombreBaseDeDatos = "censurado";

    // Crear conexión con la base de datos.
    $conn = new mysqli($nombreServidor, $nombreUsuario, $passwordBaseDeDatos, $nombreBaseDeDatos);

    // Validar la conexión de base de datos.
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn ->connect_error);
    }

    // Consulta segura para evitar inyecciones SQL.
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM a_usuarios WHERE ci='%s' AND password='%s'", mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $ci), mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password));
    $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
    $row_cnt = $resultado->num_rows;

    // Verificando si el usuario existe en la base de datos.
        if($row_cnt>0){
            // Guardo en la sesión el ci del usuario.
            $_SESSION['ci'] = $ci;

            // Redirecciono al usuario a la página principal del sitio.
            header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily"); 
            header("Location: https://ejemplo.com"); 
        } else {
            echo 'El email o password es incorrecto, <a href="index.html">vuelva a intenarlo</a>.<br/>';
        }
?>
```

También quite la linea `session_start();`